# How to get the control group values of a component loaded using DCL loadintolocation?

Tags: typescript, angular

I am loading a component using `DynamicComponentLoader.loadIntoLocation()`. The component loaded consists of control group which I want to add to the parent form. I having created a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/PFOFyd9XN5xMzwK9q0fP?p=preview). Here is the code I am trying to add to the parent form.

```
@Component({ 
  selector: 'some-component',
  template: `
    <div>  
      <label>label</label>  
      <input type="text" [ngFormControl]="childform.controls['name']">  
    </div> 
  `
})                   
class SomeComponent {
  public childform: ControlGroup;

  constructor(fbs: FormBuilder) {  
    this.childform = fbs.group({  
      'name':  ['', Validators.required]  
    });
  }
}
```

How should I add the control group of the component `SomeComponent` to the parent. I am able to add the ControlGroup of `FakeComponent` but not `SomeComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `toComponent` method is returning your `FakeComponent` instead of the `SomeComponent` like you intend it to.

```
function toComponent(template, directives) {
  @Component({ 
    selector: 'fake-component',
    template,directives
  })

  class FakeComponent {

    public fakeForm: ControlGroup;
    constructor(fb: FormBuilder) {  
      this.fakeForm = fb.group({  
        'dummy':['']
      });
      //this.myForm1.addControl('main',directives[0]);
      //this.myForm1.updateValueAndValidity();
    }
  }
  return FakeComponent; // <-- ALWAYS returns FakeComponent
}
```

Instead you need to change it to return your new component, or take the method out all together and use

```
loadIntoLocation(SomeComponent, this.elementRef,'container');
```

**Update**

I see your intentions now. And I do understand what you are trying to accomplish. However, the big issue is with the `@Component({template,directives})` part of the code. The **big** difference here is that the Directives get processed at **Compile Time** and not **Run Time**. If you look at the typescript output you'll see what I mean.

Each `@Component` directive gets translated to javascript and the references to the constructors are cemented in to the ReflectAPI `defineMetadata` functions. These do not evaluate at *runtime* like you would imagine they do, instead then run immediately setting up the underlying metadata for your component.

My suspicion of what you need to do is to use the DCL to load the `FakeComponent` which then in turn uses the DCL to load the `SomeComponent`.

Comment: I dont want to load 'SomeComponent' in the DCL method...Because my requirement is something like this...If you have a look at the demo(i updated it now) and inspect the html...The button and somecomponent lies in <FakeComponent ></FakeComponent > .I should return FakeComponent but at the same time i want to add SomeComponent ControlGroup.

Comment: @abhilashreddy Updated answer with response.

Comment: I am getting the values of form and here is the updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/PFOFyd9XN5xMzwK9q0fP?p=preview   But is there any approach that i can raise event from the button created dynamically.I Know how to raise event from Button created using BrowserDomAdapter but is there any easy approach to raise the event here in this condition?